# R function for converting data.table to named list of named vectors

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for R function that in sensible time would convert a data.table for example (in real with many 1000s entries):

```
id num1 name
id1    1    a
id1    5    f
id1    8    y
id1    5    z
id2    2    w
id2    5    k
id2    6    l
```

to a named list by 'id' column of named by 'name' column vector of 'num1' column.

Output (a list) would look like this:

```
$id1
   a f y z
   1 5 8 5
$id2
   w k l
   2 5 6
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you can use split.. but to be clear, in the list, each element is a vector or data.frame?

Comment: each element is a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` and use `setNames` to get named vector

```
lapply(split(df, df[[1]]), function(x) setNames(x$num1, x$name))

#$id1
#a f y z 
#1 5 8 5 

#$id2
#w k l 
#2 5 6
```

---

Similarly as @StudidWolf suggests, we can also use `by` here.

```
by(df,df$id,function(x) setNames(x$num1,x$name))
```

Comment: maybe use by? by(X,X$id,function(i)setNames(i$num1,i$name)); but yeah; your approach works :)

Comment: @StupidWolf yeah..`by` can be used here as well. Thanks, I updated the answer :)

Comment: If you split a data.table, you should reconsider your approach. You simply shouldn't (need to) do that. It's inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` version:

```
lst = sapply(dt[, unique(id)], function(x) {
    dt[id==x, mapply(setNames, num1, name)]
})
```

The contents of `lst` are then:

```
> lst
$id1
a f y z 
1 5 8 5 

$id2
w k l 
2 5 6
```